# Powershell loop until the output is one line

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-cli2

What i am trying to achieve is that if the output is one line and that that line gets written away in a variable. This is the code i have right now:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount
(get-azurermresourcegroup).ResourceGroupName 
$filter = Read-Host -Prompt "Please filter to find the correct resource group" 
$RGName = get-azurermresourcegroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -match $filter } 
$RGName.resourcegroupname
```

this code filters one time and after that it writes all the lines away underneath each other so the results are this:

```
ResourceGroup-Test
ResourceGroup-Test-1
ResourceGroup-Test-2
```

but the preferred output is to keep filtering until one is left

Comment: So you want to keep reading from the host until they filter specific enough to get one result? Why not use something like `Out-GridView -passthru` instead? You can force one result (from a set) and it allows the end user to find what they want without being punished for not being specific enough?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan! Only i do not know where to add it in the code, where do you reccomend me putting it in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Out-GridView

> but the preferred output is to keep filtering until one is left

Depending on what the running user chooses for filters this could be a punishing approach / needlessly complicated. If you only want *one* result how about we instead use something like `Out-GridView` to allow the user to select one result from their chosen filter.

```
$filter = Read-Host -Prompt "Please filter to find the correct resource group" 
$RGName = get-azurermresourcegroup | 
    Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -match $filter } | 
    Out-GridView -OutputMode Single 
$RGName.resourcegroupname
```

You *could* have used `-PassThru` but that allows for multiple selections. `-OutputMode Single`. So this would still have the potential for making a huge selection set if `$filter` was too vague but this is a simple way to ensure you get one result. Another caveat is that the user could click Cancel. So you might still need some loop logic: `do{..}until{}`. That depends on how resilient you want to make this process.

### Choice

If `Out-GridView` is not your speed. Another option would be to make a dynamic choice system using `$host.ui.PromptForChoice`. The following is an example that allows users to choose a subfolder from a collection.

```
$possibilities = Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Directory

If($possibilities.Count -gt 1){
    $title = "Folder Selection"
    $message = "Which folder would you like to use?"

    # Build the choices menu
    $choices = @()
    For($index = 0; $index -lt $possibilities.Count; $index++){
        $choices += New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription  ($possibilities[$index]).Name
    }

    $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]$choices
    $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0) 

    $selection = $possibilities[$result]
}

$selection
```

You should be able to adapt that into your code much in the same way that I suggested with `Out-GridView`. Be careful though about this approach. Too many options will clutter the screen.

Comment: Is there perhaps also a way to not have the gridview and that it just continues in the exisiting cmd?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Not a separate window? It does continue on

Comment: PS C:\Patht> (get-azurermresourcegroup).ResourceGroupName
>RG-test
>RG-test-1
This is what i meani would like to have the results like this

Comment: `Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -match $filter } | Select -Expand ResourceGroupName | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single` ?

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this answer from being zero?

Comment: @Brynn I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Can you expand on that?

Comment: If i use this or filtering the resource groups  > RG1 and FG2 if my input is g it will show both but if i type an X for example it just continues the script without flling in the variable